# NGINX rewrite php args

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, args

I am using NGINX 1.2.3 on Ubuntu 10.4 with php5-fpm.

```
http://example.com/step2.php?qid=RAUVGXF
```

I would like to rewrite
`/step2.php?qid=RAUVGXF`
as
`/step2/RAUVGXF`

How can I do that?

Part of my NGINX config is like below:

```
root /var/www;

location ~ .php$ {
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

Comment: To confirm, you want to browse to `http://www.example.com/step2.php?qid=RAUVGXF` and actually load the asset `/step2/RAUVGXF` correct (this is opposite of what most people try to do)? Is "RAUVGXF" a script, a static asset, or what? Do you want the URL in the browser window to change, or do you want it to remain as `http://www.example.com/step2.php?qid=RAUVGXF`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
rewrite ^/step2/ /step2.php?qid= last;
```

Comment: Thanks tried it but still the same url(no change) after page refresh(reload)

Comment: @Ronin: You have to change your code to change the URL. The `rewrite` directive just makes the server understand the new URL.

Comment: As I understand /step2/<qid> must be submitted from the php code but actually step2.php?qid=<qid> executes and nginx interprets

Comment: @Ronin: And does this not do that? (It might not; I haven't actually tried it.)

Comment: need to check with developer (I am not a code person) how he does that from the php code.. basically what I wanna see URL /step2/<qid> by running /step2.php?qid=<qid> .. will update here once we try it. this seems to be the missing piece of my puzzle...Thanks for the help..